# Unable to convert Firebase JSON to Java Object using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two activities, one to create an Assessment object, and another to list the Assessment objects in Firebase, however I've encountered an issue: the POJO is able to serialize to JSON just fine, however the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` doesn't seem to be able to return the JSON data to the object type.

Here is my object file:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Assessment {

private String company;
private String industry;
private String location;
private String product;
private String ownerId;
private String ownerName;
private boolean isDraft;
private boolean isQuickWalk;
private Map<String, Category> categories;



public Assessment() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue()
}

public Assessment(String companyName, String industryName, String locationName,
                  String productName, String ownerId, String ownerName, boolean isDraft, boolean isQuickWalk, Map<String, Category> categories) {
    this.company = companyName;
    this.industry = industryName;
    this.location = locationName;
    this.product = productName;
    this.ownerId = ownerId;
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.isDraft = isDraft;
    this.isQuickWalk = isQuickWalk;
    this.categories = categories;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return company;
}

public String getIndustryName() {
    return industry;
}

public String getLocationName() {
    return location;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return product;
}

public String getOwnerName() {
    return ownerName;
}

public boolean getIsDraft() {
    return isDraft;
}

public boolean getIsQuickWalk() {
    return isQuickWalk;
}
```

Based on this, I use this code to write to Firebase and it all works fine:

```
String key = mDatabaseRef.child(FIREBASE_ASSESSMENTS).push().getKey();
Assessment assessment = new Assessment(editCompanyText, editLocationText,
                        editIndustryText, editProductText, uid, 
currentUser.getEmail(), isDraft, isQuickWalk, null);

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put("/" + FIREBASE_ASSESSMENTS + "/" + key, 
assessment);
mDatabaseRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

However, when I try to read from the database I believe this is where the problem lies:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Assessment, ViewDraftsViewHolder> adapter;
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.draft_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Query query = mEvalRef;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Assessment> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Assessment>()
            .setQuery(query, Assessment.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Assessment, ViewDraftsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewDraftsViewHolder holder, int position, Assessment model) {
            if(model.getIsDraft()) {
                holder.companyName.setText(model.getCompanyName());
                holder.industryName.setText(model.getIndustryName());
                holder.locationName.setText(model.getLocationName());
                holder.productName.setText(model.getProductName());
                holder.ownerName.setText(model.getOwnerName());

                if(model.getIsQuickWalk()) {
                    holder.isQuickWalk.setText("Quick Walkthrough");
                } else {
                    holder.isQuickWalk.setText("Full Questionnaire");
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public ViewDraftsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.completed_and_drafts_list_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewDraftsViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    private static class ViewDraftsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView companyName;
    TextView industryName;
    TextView locationName;
    TextView productName;
    TextView ownerName;
    TextView isQuickWalk;

    public ViewDraftsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        companyName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyView);
        industryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.industryView);
        locationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationView);
        productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productView);
        ownerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ownerName);
        isQuickWalk = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.isQuickWalkView);
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong that the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is unable to convert the data back to an `Assessment` Object. Did i not set the object up correctly? Did I not set the RecyclerAdapter up correctly? This is how the data looks in Firebase

```
"-KzB39l1KH6MyEsgr6Ke" : {
  "companyName" : "testing ",
  "industryName" : "at",
  "isDraft" : true,
  "isQuickWalk" : true,
  "locationName" : "five fifteen",
  "ownerName" : "test@email.com",
  "productName" : "please ignore"
},
```

any help you can give me would be excellent, I have been struggling with wrapping my head around this for a few days. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
  Query query = mEvalRef;
```

I assume mEvalRef is a database reference, can you show it because its not clear how you query the data from the database.

just add (mEvalRef), in order to find the problem.

**Edit**

in your (Assessment) class , I noticed that there is no setter methods for the variable, add setter for each variable in the class and see if this helps.

**EDIT 2**

in your code where you try to read the values.

remove this

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Assessment> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Assessment>()
        .setQuery(query, Assessment.class)
        .build();
```

and in this line or part of the adapter initialization:

```
   adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Assessment, ViewDraftsViewHolder>(options)
```

remove the (options) parameter and change the above line of code to this:

```
      adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Assessment, ViewDraftsViewHolder>(Assessment.class, R.layout.completed_and_drafts_list_item, ViewDraftsViewHolder.class, query )
```

next remove this code:

```
        @Override
    public ViewDraftsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.completed_and_drafts_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewDraftsViewHolder(view);
    }
```

and finally change the (private) to (public) in this:

```
    private static class ViewDraftsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
```

and don't forget to keep the setters for variables in assessment class and make the variables public as I told you.

**EDIT 3**

now forget about EDIT 2 and retype your code the way you originally did it and just do this after you configured everything:

in the method where you initialize the adapter, add before this:

```
   mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this:

```
   adapter.startListening();
```

Comment: `mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mEvalRef = mReference.child(FIREBASE_ASSESSMENTS);` Is how I used it, where `FIREBASE_ASSESSMENTS` is a constant for the entry in my firebase 
Structure is like this:
app
|___assessments
|      |___{child keys}
|___users
|___etc

Comment: check the Edit and see if it helps

Comment: adding setters did not change anything i'm afraid. Wouldnt the variables technically be set on a call to a new Assessment i.e. `assessment = new Assessment(a,b,c,d,etc);`?

Comment: To cover all of my bases, I have verified that my proguard file is set up correctly

Comment: Okay look the variables are private in the assessment class, maybe they are not accessed change them to public and see what happens.

Comment: constructor for the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that you show gives an error:
`Error:(70, 19) error: constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<T,VH> cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Assessment>
found: Class<Assessment>,int,Class<ViewDraftsViewHolder>,Query
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T,VH are type-variables:
T extends Object declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
VH extends ViewHolder declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: Also making the private variables in the assessment class public added duplicate values to the firebase

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: Ok i may have lied, the views are now inflating but it is still not pulling data even after correcting some capitalization differences. There much be something wrong with my POJOs so I will have to look into that on monday

Comment: NEVERMIND MY VIEW WAS TOO LARGE YOU'RE A MIRACLEWORKER